# Datagridview performance - looping through the rows vs row-event-driven calculation

Tags: .net, datagridview

In Winforms .Net Framework application, I have datagridview with 3 columns, bound to a datatable. Two first columns are bound to the columns in the datatable; I want the 3rd unbound column calculated basing on the first 2 columns.

I can achieve it either by the loop going through all rows in the datagridview and calculating the 3rd column

```
    this.TABLE1TableAdapter.Fill(this.DataSet1.TABLE1);
    foreach (DataGridViewRow c in DataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        var r = c.DataBoundItem.row;
        c.Cells("column3").Value = string.Format("{0}/{1}", r.column1, r.column2);
    }
```

or by calculating it "on the fly" in the datagridview's event "CellFormatting"

```
    private void DataGridView1_CellFormatting(DataGridView sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 3)
        {
            DataSet1.TABLE1Row r = sender.Rows(e.RowIndex).DataBoundItem.row;
            e.Value = string.Format("{0}/{1}", r.column1, r.column2);
        }
    }
```

Both methods produce the expected result, but the event-based one takes 6 seconds, while loop-based one takes 60. I expected that if there was any difference, it would rather be in favor of the loop. Can somebody explain?

Comment: Cell.Formatting is run only for the visible cells. In both case it is very slow to have 6 and 60 seconds. Filling at database query level should be much faster than. If you are really filling the DGV with too many rows maybe you should read about virtual mode.

Comment: >Cell.Formatting is run only for the visible cells - 
Thanks, I see.

Answer (score 0):

There are two more option you can use.

1. Change the Datatable Select Query.
   like select a,b,a+b c from table
2. you can use a List where there will be third property set from column1 & column2.